# Limit fetch results from javascript fetch

Tags: javascript

Is there a function similar to `q=sort&` or `q=created:&` to limit number of results from a JavaScript fetch?

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => { }
```

Comment: What about `.filter`?

Comment: This didn't deserve a downvote, good question and good description to it, I was looking for the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution, of course, is if the `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` endpoint documents a limit or filter parameter you can send it.

Assuming the result is an array, or contains an array, the very-much-second-best solution is to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) the result (to apply criteria) and/or [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice) the result (to just apply a limit):

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        data = data.filter(entry => entry.created > someValue) // Created after X
                   .slice(0, 1000);                            // Limit to 1000
        // ...use data...
    })
    .catch(error => {        // <=== Don't forget to handle errors
        // Handle error...
    });
```

---

Note: Your `fetch` call is missing a check on `res.ok` (it's not just you, a **lot** of people make that mistake so many that [I wrote it up on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)):

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then((res) => {                                      // ***
        if (!res.ok) {                                    // ***
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);  // ***
        }                                                 // ***
    })                                                    // ***
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        data = data.filter(entry => entry.created > someValue)
                   .slice(0, 1000);
        // ...use data...
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle error...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 fetch(`http://localhost:3000/services?_page=${page}&_limit=3`)
```

You can add a payload to the body of the fetch, see above.

Answer (score -1):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch:

```
postData(`http://example.com/answer`, {answer: 42})
  .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))) // JSON-string from `response.json()` call
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

function postData(url = ``, data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
        cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: "same-origin", // include, same-origin, *omit
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
        referrer: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    })
    .then(response => response.json()); // parses response to JSON
}
```

Not sure what exactly you want so here are 3 possibilities:

1. You can add a payload to the body of the fetch, see above.
2. You could simply url-encode it.
3. On res.json()) .then((data) => { } ... You can filter the data you want.

Hope this helps.