# Stop request after X-amount is fetched

Tags: javascript

I want to fetch an external, third-party api from client side. But the feed is huge (160,000 objects in one array)
I have no control over the external api.

Is it possible to set a max-limit, to amount of bytes maybe? So I could fetch about 50,000 objects in this case? Cause it is loading way too long

I have been reading about `axios` and the `maxContentLength` and `maxBodyLength` but without any luck - it doesn't have any effect.

Also, the api doesn't support any pagination like `?size=20&page=1`

So it is possible using XMLHttpRequest, I could tell in the comments. But is the same solution possible using fetch function? Since we don't have this e.loaded

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning - it is supposed to be called from client side

Comment: There's [an issue opened](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1491) as well as fix suggested for it, which has been applied in axios 0.19.0. Which is the version you use in your project?

Comment: After some investigation it seems that issue is still not solved. It's a bit tricky: the fix suggested [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/1493/files) is not intended to receive a part of the message then stop, it justs throws an error immediately after receiving headers with Content-Length > maxContentLength specified.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557562/limit-fetch-results-from-javascript-fetch

Comment: @raina77ow it was exactly what I checked already, but thanks.

Comment: @absolutebeginner sadly this is not solving my issue, because it still has to fetch the whole feed before you can filter

Comment: Well, I'm working on PoC to solve this, I'll add this to an answer; may be it'll be helpful.

Comment: Maybe you could use GraphQL: https://graphql.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's a small-and-dirty PoC just to test the idea (kudos to [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/api.php) for that wonderful and truly public API):

```js
async function limitedFetch(url, maxBytes) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onprogress = (ev) => {
        console.log(`Received ${ev.loaded} bytes`);
        if (ev.loaded < maxBytes) return;
        resolve(ev.target.responseText);
        xhr.abort();
      };
      xhr.onload = (ev) => {
        resolve(ev.target.responseText);
      };
      xhr.onerror = (ev) => { reject(new Error(ev.target.status)) }

      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
    }
    catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}

const out = document.querySelector('pre');
const filter = document.querySelector('#filter');
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(
  btn => btn.addEventListener('click', async (ev) => {
    const rateLimit = ev.target.dataset.rate || Infinity;
    const cacheBuster = '&' + Date.now();
    const animeApiUrl = 
    `https://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/api.xml?title=~${filter.value}`;
    out.textContent = 'Waiting...';
    console.clear();
    try {
      const response = await limitedFetch(animeApiUrl + cacheBuster, rateLimit);
      out.textContent = `Received ${response.length} characters:
  ${response}`;
    }
    catch (err) {
      out.textContent = `Oh noes! ${err.message}
  ${err.stack}`;
    }
  })
);
```

```html
<input id="filter" value="a" style="width: 5em"></input>
<button type="button">Release the FULL Kraken!</button>
<button type="button" data-rate="1000">Release the Rated Kraken!</button>
<pre></pre>
```

The key here is using `onprogress` event of XMLHttpRequest to track the count of bytes received (that's `loaded` property on ProgressEvent object). When it overflows the limit, the fetcher resolves immediately - and drops the corresponding request.

Play with different release buttons, and you'll see the difference in both bytes received overall - and the number of `console.log` messages (those are fired for each received chunk of data).

Now the catch: with default filter (just 'a') 'rated' requests never stop at exactly 1000 bytes; that's not how chunks work. Instead there's always one chunk not greater than ~50K bytes; with 'rated' request, that's the only one, with unrated, there'll be three more or so.

Comment: Really appreciate your effort, I will give it a shot and get back :)

Comment: Thank you! This will definitly help me a lot! Is it ok i'm gonna extend your script and publish is to npm? I am gonna use it in several projects myself

Comment: I assume it is not possible to make somekind of "Read more" functionality and then fetch the next x-amount of bytes from last stop

Comment: Well... it is possible IF the server supports it on their side. The idea is employing so-called [Range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests), but I assume that's not your case (as it'd greatly simplify the original task too).

Comment: Ah ok. And no, I don't have any control to the server, since it is 3rd party.. But this will definitly help. Thanks!

Comment: is the same solution possible, but using fetch function and not XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Well, there are two key parts in this solution: `xhr.abort()` for stopping the request, and `onprogress` event handler. While `fetch` seems to support request stopping through [AbortSignal](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/abortable-fetch), progress (as well as events in general) are just not what it was written for. So no, I don't think it's possible - at least as things are in Nov 2020.